# How to check if string is .inarray

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I check if a string is contained with my array? Here's how I'm putting the array together...

```
 // get the select
 var $dd = $('#product-variants');

 if ($dd.length > 0) { // make sure we found the select we were looking for

 // save the selected value
 var selectedVal = $dd.val();

 // get the options and loop through them
 var $options = $('option', $dd);
 var arrVals = [];
 $options.each(function(){
     // push each option value and text into an array
     arrVals.push({
         val: $(this).val(),
         text: $(this).text()
     });
 });
};
```

I want to check if "Kelly Green" is contained within the array if it is I want to .show a li

```
$("#select-by-color-list li#kelly-green").show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's inbuilt [`.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method:

```
if($.inArray('Kelly Green', arrVals) != -1) {
    $("#select-by-color-list li#kelly-green").show();
}
```

Comment: Be careful using this, the check is incorrect, it should be `if($.inArray('Kelly Green', arrVals) != -1) {`, `0` *is* a valid result, if the element is the first in the array you'll get `0`, `-1` is what you should be checking for.

Comment: @Nick Craver, you're right, I've fixed the answer. I naturally assumed that jQuery would not duplicate JS's own idiocies and would return rather just a boolean value indicating the precense of a value. :)

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct so far as use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) here, *however* the usage is off, it should be:

```
if($.inArray('Kelly Green', arrVals) != -1) {
  $("#select-by-color-list li#kelly-green").show();
}
```

[`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns the *position* in the array (which may be `0` if it's first...so it's in there, but that `if()` would be false).  To check if it's present, use `!= -1`, which is what it'll return if the element is *not* found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
console.log($.inArray('Kelly Green', arrVals);

if($.inArray('Kelly Green', arrVals)
{
  $("#select-by-color-list li#kelly-green").show();
}
```

Possible dupe:
[Need help regarding jQuery $.inArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169106/need-help-regarding-jquery-inarray)

Comment: You got the parameters wrong way around, it's `.inArray(value, array)`.

Comment: @ Noah and Tatu, Nice one! I was thinking about it to hard! Works great! Thanks very much