# What's the preferred operator when comparing indexOf result with -1, "!=" or ">"?

Tags: javascript

What's the preferred operator when comparing the result of indexOf with -1, "!=" or ">"? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either is ok here, you just care that it's not `-1`. *Personally*, I prefer `!=`, since I'm saying it's explicitly *not* something that way...and that's the check we're performing. For example:

```
if(arr.indexOf("thing") != -1)
```

It's checking explicitly for *not* that single value, the unique `-1` result you get when it's not found.  With `>`, you're checking for *any* other value...I find this more explicit, just use what's clearer *for you*.

Another reason I steer clear of `>` is that *far* too many times (in both questions *and* answers) on StackOverflow I see `if(arr.indexOf("thing") > 0)` which is almost **never** the correct check.

Comment: That's funny, I don't thik I've ever seen that `> 0` error here.

Comment: @T.J. - I usually comment and see it corrected, but I'd say at least 1-200 times I've seen it, *far* too often.  Here's a quick example from a few days ago fresh in my mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555723/how-to-check-if-string-is-inarray That particular one's not `> 0` but they are comparing to `0`...but I do see exactly `> 0` every so often here.

Comment: Oh, I *believe* you. I've certainly seen that error in code, just not here. You must get there first. ;-)

Comment: A third option: `if (~arr.indexOf('thing'))`. It's more succinct and clever, but less explicit and actually [slightly slower](http://jsperf.com/bitwise-not-vs-gt-indexof/4).

How does it work? It checks if the bitwise NOT of the value returned by indexOf is truthy. It turns out that the bitwise NOT of any integer except -1 is truthy, so it works nicely for this test.

Answer (score 2):

As [Nick said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578525/whats-the-preferred-operator-when-comparing-indexof-result-with-1-or/4578536#4578536), either is fine. I prefer `>= 0` because then I'm coding a positive:

```
index = str.indexOf('foo');
if (index >= 0) {
    // Do something with `index`
}
else {
    // 'foo' wasn't found
}
```

Comment: I second this approach. "Coding a positive" -- always makes the code more upbeat :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would say `!=`. You said it yourself actually:

> when comparing the result of indexOf with -1

Moreover, `!=` is faster than `>`.

Comment: If you're worried about speed, use `!==`, not `!=`. :-) But I'd really have to see the real-world tangible difference to care, and I'm quite sure that other aspects of the surrounding code will *totally* swamp the comparator difference.

Comment: Making the *silly assertion* that `!=` is faster than `>` or *has any applicable interest* is just dumb here. Please don't "put forward" these useless u-optimizations.